# possible to update a file (csv preferably) with node aws-sdk?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, fs, aws-sdk-nodejs

I understand how to read a file, but I'm not sure how to create a stream to update the file. Essentially, I want to run the following on an s3 object:

`fs.writeFileSync('targetFile.csv', new_data, {flag: 'a+'})`

The context is, I have an elastic beanstalk app containing a form. On submit, I want to capture some of the data and write to file csv file that lives in a s3 bucket. If there's a better way solution, I'm open to that.

UPDATE:
Here's my solution, but I feel there should be a cleaner way:

```
const params = {
    Bucket: 'BUCKET',
    Key: 'file.csv',
  }
  s3.getObject(params, function(err, data){
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else {
      // since I'm adding to csv: add a new line and comma-seperate new values
      params.Body = data.Body.toString('utf-8') + '\n additionanal cell1, additional cell2, additionalcell3'; 
      s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else console.log(data);
      });
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a stream to `AWS.S3::putObject` in the same way you would pass a buffer or string:

```
const S3 = new AWS.S3({region: 'us-west-2'});
s3.putObject({
    Bucket: 'bucket',
    Key: 'key',
    Body: fs.createReadStream('path/to/file'),
});
```

One thing to keep in mind: if the request need to be retried due to a networking issue, the AWS SDK won't be able to replay the stream. The upshot is that transient network issues will be immediately surfaced to your application instead of the request being retried.

Comment: the problem I'm having is the file i want to update lives on s3, so i don't _believe_ i have have a path. Sorry I didn't describe that thoroughly, but I ended up nested a putObject inside a getObject (see above)